# Microsoft VB.NET naming convention

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

Is there any standard naming convention for VB.NET ?

Based your programming experiences, would like to share your naming convention for VB.NET ?

Are there any guides for this kind of good practice besides [patterns & practices](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=guidanceExplorer) Guidance Explorer and [Guidance Share](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/Main%5FPage) ?

Thanks. Happy Weekend.

Comment: You know, you could pick one of these as an answer. Any one you want. Just pick one! I'm sure there is an answer here that fits the need of this question....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Mehrdad said, VB.NET follows the [General .NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). More specificly:

- Types, events, read-only static fields, methods, namespaces, properties: PascalCase
- Parameters: camelCase
- Acronyms of two characters: DB, with the exception of Id and Ok
- Acronyms of three or more characters: Html or html, depending on context, but never HTML
- Compound words: Hashtable, not HashTable, except for some common terms like FileName
- Do not use separators like hyphens (-) or underscores (_) between words
- Do not use Hungarian notation

Comment: Actually, ID has a special rule and should be spelled Id according to the MS conventions. Other two-letter acronyms should be all uppercase, though.

Comment: VB.NET is case insensitive, so how do you name the corresponding field of a property? How about local variables? Could you please complete your answer? Thanks

Comment: The standard I've seen is to start backing fields with underscore. So, `private _name As String` going along with `Public Property Name As String`

Comment: Why not use Hungarian notation?  Please explain.  I haven't done MS programming in a while, but I am taking a VB class and this is still what they are teaching.

Comment: Hungarian notation is meaningless. Give variables the name according to what it is. For an integral number (e.g. size or count) it does rarely matter if it is an int or a long. Errors should be detected by the compiler. This is even more true for non-standard types.

Answer (score 4):

I use this guide on "net Naming Conventions and Programming Standards - Best Practices":
http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET shares the naming convention of the .NET Framework. PascalCase for types and public stuff, camelCase otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Visual Studio "Code Analysis" to check your code against several Microsoft-sanctioned naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306894/naming-conventions-in-c). It is essentially the same question regarding C#, however most of of the links and answers provided apply to both languages.